# Are FOSS4G conference presentations available online?

Tags: references, education, open-source-gis

I'm wondering if anyone has knows of links to a website(s) where previous [FOSS4G](http://foss4g.org/) conference presentations are available online.  I would like to:

- watch recorded video presentations,
- listen to audio recordings, or
- read through detailed PPT presentations (more than just abstracts)

In particular, I am interested in videos from the [FOSS4G-North America](http://foss4g-na.org/) 2013 conference, but this would be a good archive of locations to find any past FOSS4G conference presentations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Global FOSS4G**

Slides:

- [2017 - Boston](http://2017.foss4g.org/post_conference/#slides)
- [2013 - Nottingham](http://elogeo.nottingham.ac.uk/xmlui/handle/url/121/browse?type=dateissued) (elogeo archive website)

Videos:

- [2016 - Bonn](http://video.foss4g.org/foss4g2016/videos/index.php)
- [2014 - Portland](http://vimeo.com/foss4g/videos/)
- [2013 - Nottingham](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWW0CjV-TafaBjkroiOxcQw8NdOQ_fhu2)

**National**

Videos:

- [2016  North America](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_LGEn4G1x8r99HkY_RfJNlDYB9LDzMj0) (youtube playlist)

Comment: http://elogeo.nottingham.ac.uk is down :/ , any ressource to download FOSS4G PDX 2014 workshops

Answer (score 4):

I have also recently found there is a [FOSS4GNA YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/FOSS4GNA/videos), however, it looks like the most recent uploads are from the 2012 conference.

There are a also number of slide decks from FOSS4G North America 2013 are available from http://lanyrd.com/2013/foss4gna-2013/coverage/.

I have also been able to find some of the recent presentations by searching for their titles on on http://www.slideshare.net and https://speakerdeck.com/

Esri has also linked to some of their FOSS4G-NA presentations at: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/05/21/esri-foss4g-na-2013/